# apply function in data table for conditional removal of row

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data table, `dt`:

```
           V1                      V2             V3   PubMedCounts
1: 0000100005                100-00-5     CAS Number              6
2: 0000100005 1-Chloro-4-nitrobenzene DescriptorName             12
3: 0000100005                    aahs DescriptorName            111
4: 0000100005                    PNCB        Synonym             35
```

Also, I have a data table, `ew`, which has only one columns with words, like:

```
          V1
1:       aah
2:     aahed
3:    aahing
4:      aahs
5:  aardvark
```

from `dt` data table, i need to remove all the rows which have `V2` size less than or equal to 5 or present in `ew` data table.

Example, from `dt` table, i would remove 3rd and 4th row.

I would like to use apply function to make it efficient as its pretty big data set

Comment: Why is the 4th row removed? Because `"PNCB" < 5 ` ?

Comment: So  you mean you want to remove character strings having 4 or fewer characters?

Comment: yes,, my mistake, it should be less than or equal to 5. I edited the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I would do:

```
dt[!ew, on = c(V2 = "V1")][nchar(V2) > 5]
```

which gives:

```
       V1                      V2             V3 PubMedCounts
1: 100005                100-00-5     CAS_Number            6
2: 100005 1-Chloro-4-nitrobenzene DescriptorName           12
```

Applying the conditions in the other order might be faster:

```
dt[nchar(V2) > 5][!ew, on = c(V2 = "V1")]
```

This prevents matching on things in `dt` that would be deleted in the next step anyway.

A third possibility is using:

```
dt[nchar(V2) > 5 & !( V2 %chin% ew$V1 )]
```

---

Used data:

```
dt <- structure(list(V1 = c(100005L, 100005L, 100005L, 100005L), V2 = c("100-00-5", 
"1-Chloro-4-nitrobenzene", "aahs", "PNCB"), V3 = c("CAS_Number", 
"DescriptorName", "DescriptorName", "Synonym"), PubMedCounts = c(6L, 
12L, 111L, 35L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2", "V3", "PubMedCounts"
), row.names = c(NA, -4L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))

ew <- structure(list(V1 = c("aah", "aahed", "aahing", "aahs", "aardvark")), .Names = "V1", row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Thanks @Frank & `@Jaap`, I have been running around & unable to create the example myself to test.